# How to traverse through elements in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a simple table structure in which i am able to change the order of table rows by clicking up and down buttons.Now what i am trying to achieve is that when a row becomes the first in the order, Up button should get disabled and when a row becomes last in the list, Down button should be disabled and to achieve this disabling effect i want to use only css.So is it possible ?How can i reach/traverse to the up and down button with css.

```js
$(".order").click(function() {
  var prevTr = $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr');
  var nextTr = $(this).closest('tr').next('tr');
  var currentTr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var getClick = $(this).data('rel');
  (getClick > 1) ? currentTr.insertAfter(nextTr): currentTr.insertBefore(prevTr);
});
```

```css
/*adding red color to show disabled effect */


 table tr:last-child  td:first-child .order:first-child  {

   background: red;

 }

 table tr:first-child td:first-child .order:first-child {

   background: red;

 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
      <button data-rel="1" class="order">Up</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button data-rel="2" class="order">Down</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>
      <button data-rel="1" class="order">Up</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button data-rel="2" class="order">Down</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>
      <button data-rel="1" class="order">Up</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button data-rel="2" class="order">Down</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>
      <button data-rel="1" class="order">Up</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button data-rel="2" class="order">Down</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: at the moment via css you can't traverse up to parent element. although this feature will be available when css4 arrives.

Answer (score 1):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2uhp3ue5/1/)**

Yes you can do it, try following :

```
table tr:first-child td:nth-child(2){
    display:none;
}

table tr:last-child td:nth-child(3){
    display:none;
}
```

That will Hide the button, to disable it try :

```
opacity: 0.65; 
cursor: not-allowed;
```

instead of :

```
display:none;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Alignment is not proper.

Comment: thanks but is it supported in ie 8 as i am supporting ie 8 at the moment

Comment: Thanks @SarjanDesai, updated my answer, check now please.

Comment: I don't know @imGaurav i'm using v.11, but you can try it.

Answer (score 1):

:first-child is one of the CSS 2.1 selectors it is therefore available since IE8

if you have any questions about wether you can use a functionality with an old browser, This resource is very useful.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2